# Trouble with Rails array methods

Tags: arrays, ruby-on-rails

I have a block of deprecated Ruby on Rails code which is the beginning of a rake file and doesn't depend on anything except accessing the Protein class, which it can (inherited from an earlier version of the project)

```
task :import_merops_cleavages do
  require "#{Rails.root}/config/environment"
  require 'bio'  
  require 'merops'
  require_relative '../../app/models/protein.rb'


  proteases = Protein.includes(:drs).map(&:drs).where(db_name: 'MEROPS').uniq
  @total = proteases.count  
  puts "starting import of #{@total} proteases"
  @added = 1 
  @padded =1
```

Every time I try to rake this particular task, the rake aborts and I get the same error message

`NoMethodError: undefined method where for #<Array:0x00007f88a625d290> Did you mean?  when`

I have tried to use other methods to get rid of the where or rearrange things but keep the logic the same, but am at a loss. If anyone has an idea how to resolve this, I would be very grateful

Edit: this is the main visual relational documentation for the application, but I can explain anything that may not make sense.

[image]

Comment: This smells like something that should actually be done in the database. Can you include the models, schema and what the actual expected output is?

Comment: It could possibly be  temporarily patched with `Protein.includes(:drs).map(&:drs).select{ |r| r.db_name == 'MEROPS' }.uniq`. but its still got a really bad smell.

Comment: All the things @max said. I don't know where `db_name` is e.g. in `Protein` or whatever drs is but the use of `includes` and `uniq` seems like it would be better as `left_joins` or `joins` and `distinct` via the database connection.

Comment: What about `Protein.includes(:drs).where(db_name: 'MEROPS').map(&:drs).uniq` ?

Comment: @BTL `db_name` is probably not on the proteins table. Its impossible to know anything really due to the lack of detail.

Comment: @max I've added a diagram that hopefully helps! db_name is on the drs table, and drs and proteins are connected by the protein id

Comment: `Drs.where(db_name: 'MEROPS')` should do it.

Comment: @SimranRai While the diagram is better then nothing you should not expect any quality answers unless you put the effort in and provide the related models and the relevant portion of the schema. Good questions get good answers. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0):

The error is correct, the `where` method is not available on Arrays. 
It can only be used on rails models.

The `map` method returns an array, so I reckon you're issue is there.. try removing the `.map` and see if that solves this issue.

So I'd imagine something like this might work:

```
proteases = Protein.all.where(db_name: 'MEROPS').uniq
```

Tell us more about what Protein is.. better yet share the code for it.